# c++ vector with strict ownership semantics

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector

This is **not** a question about putting std::auto_ptr into std::vector.

Is there some vector equivalent of `std::auto_ptr` in `std::`, `std::tr1::` or `boost::`? I use `std::auto_ptr` in function parameters and return values to decalre ownership semantics of these functions. But this way I can pass only single objects. As a temporary solution for vectors I have this:

```
std::auto_ptr<std::vector<std::tr1::shared_ptr<ClassExample> > > fx(....);
```

which, I suppose, by introducing boost, I will be able to change into this:

```
std::auto_ptr<std::vectro<boost::unique_ptr<ClassExample> > >f(...);
```

in order to define strict ownership passing, but it seems to be quite complicated. To simplify it, I can use

```
std::vector<boost::unique_ptr<ClassExample> > f(...);
```

as the price for deep copy of the vector is not high, but I am still curious if there is something that I can use like this:

```
auto_vector<ClassExample> f(...);
```

meaning that the function is releasing ownership of all the objects and the vector internal data array is not deeply copied.

Comment: I think this is one of those "what if everyone wanted one" problems. If `auto_vector`, then why not `auto_deque`, `auto_set`, `shared_vector`, `unique_unordered_multiset`, basically every combination of any smart pointer type with any class. Template syntax is wordy, typedefs can help with that, but it's usually the user's problem. That's even ignoring that you want `auto_vector<ClassExample>` specifically to contain `unique_ptr` rather than anything else.

Comment: I think that you got a few assumptions wrong, in particular most compilers will be able to optimize the return by value not to require a new object, so dynamic allocation of the vector itself is an unneeded complication to the problem.

Comment: Joe: where is `unique_ptr` defined in tr1?

Comment: You're right, it's only in C++11. `unique_ptr` would be of no use in tr1, as it requires r-value references to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any particular reason as to why you need to maintain a vector of pointers, the first solution would be to ditch all the complexity and go for the simple:

```
std::vector<Type> f();
```

Ownership of the objects is *unique* (the vector owns them), and while the code *looks* like it is copying the vector on return it will be [optimized away](http://definedbehavior.blogspot.com/2011/08/value-semantics-copy-elision.html) in most cases.

If you *need* the objects inside the vector to be dynamically allocated due to some other requirement (objects must be allocated through a factory, they are pointers to derived types, or they cannot *move* due to vector growth -- code maintains references/pointers) that you are not showing then I would go for a `boost::ptr_vector` that will maintain ownership of the contained objects. Again, return by value:

```
boost::ptr_vector<Type> f();
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a C++11 solution - it requires an implementation that provides r-value references and has a standard library updated to include move constructors and `std::unique_ptr`.

Just return `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` - that type *can't* be copied, as `std::unique_ptr<T>` isn't copyable. The compiler will either use the move constructor when returning, which will not invoke a deep copy or will apply the RVO and elide the construction of a new object.

Comment: For that matter, a `std::vector<T>&&` can be moved too!

Comment: Presumably he's storing base class pointers or has another reason to store by pointer rather than by value.

Comment: I very much doubt returning a reference (to possibly a local variable) would be such a great idea. AFAIK, you return by value and if copy elision is legal, then the compiler will choose moving.

Comment: @UncleBens; You're absolutely right. I can't believe I did that. Oops.